# Canvas rect's with the same size at different locations are drawn at different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm drawing two `rect`'s inside my `canvas`, both of which are specified to be 40 wide and 20 tall.

The first `rect` has its top-left corner at 0,0 while the other one has its top-left corner at 60,40.

The one beginning at 60,40 is massive compared to the first. Even though their size should be the same

I am using [Infinite Canvas](https://www.infinite-canvas.org/) for my project, but this issue appears to happen whether I include this or not.

Here is a fiddle with Infinite Cavnas: https://jsfiddle.net/dgLt3o48/2/

And here is a fiddle without it: https://jsfiddle.net/dgLt3o48/1/

Comment: Couldn't find a correct dupe in a reasonable time. If someone has it please ping me.

Answer (score 1):

The [`rect()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect) is defined as `rect(x, y, width, height)`, not as `rect(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. Your second rectangle is thus not a 20 x 40 rectangle, but a 100 x 60 one.

Also beware that if you don't call [`ctx.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath), when you call `stroke()` all the path is drawn again, this means your smaller rectangle is currently drawn twice.